# Site security for Kirby CMS

Tags: security, kirby

I am creating a site where clients will need to securely upload documents and enter secure information. I was hoping to add additional security to the site and wanted to know if there were any plugins or kirby additions I could add to my site. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2021:** Thanks [@Daniel Groner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5798818/daniel-groner) for the comment about the security plugins for Kirby at https://getkirby.com/plugins?category=security. There are also [user permissions](https://getkirby.com/docs/guide/users/permissions) you can adjust.

**Original Answer:**
I haven't seen any plugins specifically for security on the Kirby plugins site (http://getkirby-plugins.com/). However, if you haven't seen it, a new security page was added to the Kirby CMS docs <strike>in August 2015 (http://getkirby.com/docs/security)</strike> https://getkirby.com/docs/guide/security (2021). Here they list the main ways to make your site more secure. A few things stood out to me:

- Keeping Kirby updated is important like any CMS "in order to fix possible issues and vulnerabilities."
- Getting an SSL certificate for user login so you can use HTTPS.
- Check out the many other important steps for securing a site in the
  security doc (see link above).

Comment: This is a old one, but if someone stumbles upon this, in the meantime there are some security plugins added here:
https://getkirby.com/plugins?category=security

Especially "Content Security Policy" and "Doctor" can be interesting.